# How to update a URL sending to chrome or firefox when a process in c# is started

Tags: c#, url, browser, process

I begin the process like this:

> Process p = new Process();
>
> p.StartInfo.Arguments = "http://www.gooogle.com";
>
> p.Start();

When the process is created I want to send another URL to that browser, I launch 8 browser  one in each one of the 8 monitors I have to track info(statistics), how can I only **update the URL** instead killing the **process** and create another 8 **browser**?

Comment: I don't think that there is a way to do this unless Chrome or Firefox specifically implements a method. You can't, in general, do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sort of browser manipulation will have to be done using JavaScript and the browser will need to send a request to your site/service before your response (JSON, AJAX) comes back to update the URL.

Outside of that, not knowing more about what you're trying to accomplish I don't think anyone can really say what the best pattern you can use is for that.